# Adding a UIBarButton in the bottom right hand side of the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I would like to make my add button be in the bottom right hand side of my the screen but when ever I add a UIBarButton it goes to the left and I can't move it to where I want. Also because I have a tableView I can't add a normal button because it just becomes a part of the table view. I attached a photo of my main.storyBoard below.

[Main.StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSYAu.png)

Essentially, I just want to move the add button from the left to the right.

Comment: The answers that were given were outdated so I had to ask again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the lower bar is a UIToolbar...

Adding a Flexible Space Bar Button Item to the left of your UIBarButtonItem should push the item to the right end, assuming there are no other items.

The Flexible Space Bar Button Item is at the bottom of the Object library:

[image: Flexible Space Bar Button Item]